# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'username' of undefined

Tags: javascript, html, react-redux

i get Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'username' of undefined when i navigate to an external page an try to go back. On render it hits the else statement where i return false. Is there a way to avoid this error to be thrown?

```
render() {
        const videos = this.randomHomeList();
        const users = this.props.users;
        const videoList = videos.map(video => {
            if (video) {
                const owner = users.filter(user => user.id === video.owner_id)
                if (owner) { 
                    const videoOwner = owner.find(user => user.username)
                    return (
                        <ul key={video.id} >
                            <div className="home-list-item">
                                <div className="home-video-header">
                                    <h2 className="home-video-header-1">Added to</h2>
                                    <h2 className="home-video-header-2">Foxeo Staff Picks</h2>
                                </div>
                                <Link to={`/play/${video.id}`}>
                                    <video 
                                        className="home-video"
                                        src={video.video_url}
                                        poster=""
                                        width="320" 
                                        height="240"
                                        >    
                                    </video>
                                </Link>
                                <h2 className="video-title">{video.video_title}</h2>
                                <h2 className="video-upload-date">uploaded {this.dateCreated(video.created_at)}</h2>
                                <h2 className="video-owner-name">{videoOwner.username}</h2>
                            </div> 
                        </ul>
                    )
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        })
```

[image: error message]

Answer (score 3):

You can place a check over here and do like below:

```
 <h2 className="video-owner-name">{videoOwner ? videoOwner.username : ""}</h2>
```

Comment: @user13790968 Could you please accept the answer by clicking on tick besides the answer if it helped you. Thanks :)

Comment: Could you please accept the answer by clicking on tick besides the answer. Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use type safe operator.

**? is the Safe Navigation Operator**. It checks whether the variable is null or undefined in template. In case of null and undefined, that value will not throw an error.

```
 <h2 className="video-owner-name">{videoOwner?.username}</h2>
```

And second option is use of ternary operator as suggested in previous answer.

```
 <h2 className="video-owner-name">{videoOwner ? videoOwner.username : ""}</h2>
```

Comment: ?. is also called optional chaining.